# Limit of $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+\sin^2x}$ as $x\to0$ and proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

I computed the limit using the limit theorems and the answer is obviously $0$. So now I am attempting to prove it using the $\epsilon,\delta$  definition.

$f(x)=\frac{x}{1+\sin^2x}$

$|\frac{x}{1+\sin^2x}|<\epsilon$ if $|x|<\delta$

$|x|<\epsilon|1+\sin^2x|$

$|\sin x|<1$ $\implies$ $|\sin^2x|<1$ $\implies$ $1+|\sin^2x|<2$ $\implies$ $|1+\sin^2x|<1+|\sin^2x|<2$ $\implies$  $|1+\sin^2x|<2$ $\implies$ $\epsilon|1+\sin^2x|<2\epsilon$

Finally,

$|x|<\epsilon|1+\sin^2x|<2\epsilon$ $\implies$ $|x|<2\epsilon=\delta$

But when I plug $\epsilon=0.2$ then the $\delta=0.4$. If I put my $x=0.3<0.4$ then the answer is $0.3>0.2=\epsilon$.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Also sometimes Spivak assumes (for example in $|x^2-a^2|<\epsilon$ if $|x-a|<\delta$) that $|x-a|<1$ and chooses $\min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{2|a|+1})$ I cant understand how is it possible to make the assumption that $|x-a|<1=\delta$ if our objective IS to find $\delta$ to prove that this $\delta$ exists for every $\epsilon$. Isnt this circular reasoning ? Otherwise we can just choose that $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{10000000}$ (10000000 is an arbitrary number that makes delta very small).

Also in the example $|x^2-a^2|<\epsilon$ if $|x-a|<\delta$ assuming by some magical means that $|x-a|<1$ then $|x|-|a|<|x-a|<1$ $\implies$ $|x|<1 + |a|$ $\implies$ $|x+a|<|x|+|a|<2|a|+1$ $\implies$ $\frac{1}{|x+a|}>\frac{1}{2|a|+1}$ $\implies$ $\frac{\epsilon}{|x+a|}>\frac{\epsilon}{2|a|+1}$. And since $|x-a|<\frac{\epsilon}{|x+a|} >\frac{\epsilon}{2|a|+1}$ isn't it WRONG to write $|x-a|< \frac{\epsilon}{2|a|+1}$ since we DONT know if  $|x-a|< \frac{\epsilon}{2|a|+1}$ is true or not ?

Apologies for the long question but limits have been utterly confusing me for a long while now.

Comment: Note that the denominator is positive and $\ge 1$ which should help somewhat.

Comment: @markbennet I realize the denominator is positive but I don't think that affects any of the inequalities since I took that into account ? Sorry if I don't get your point clearly.

Comment: I think it is simpler to use that to show that $|f(x)|\le |x|$ which basically gets you done.

Comment: @markbennet WHY is my proof wrong although it is logical ?

Comment: EDIT: The problem was that I assumed the converse.

Comment: v glad that you have now understood what is going on - that will serve you well as you progress - good work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wish to prove that $$\forall \varepsilon >0\,\exists \delta >0\,\forall x\in \mathbb R\left(|x|<\delta\implies |f(x)|<0\right).$$

Let $\varepsilon >0$ and set $\delta:=\varepsilon.$ Now take $x\in \mathbb R$ and assume $|x|<\delta\color{grey}{=\varepsilon}$.

One has $|f(x)|=\left|\dfrac {x}{1+(\sin(x))^2}\right|\leq |x|<\delta=\varepsilon$, as required.

---

Regarding the Spivak example, from what I gather he is considering two cases, either $\delta =1$ is good enough, or it isn't (these cases depend on $\varepsilon$). If it is the second case, $\delta=\dfrac{\epsilon}{2|a|+1}$ is good enough. Either way $\delta =\min\left(1,\frac{\epsilon}{2|a|+1}\right)$ takes care of every thing.

Comment: From my understanding, aren't we SUPPOSED to find $\delta$ and that means we can't assume it ? Also suppose 1 is NOT good enough, then isn't using $|x-a|<1$ wrong in the proof(otherwise I can just choose $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{1000000}$ and that's it ? Also how do you know if 1 is good enough or not. Also WHY is my proof wrong ? I followed all the steps in Spivak.

Comment: @DemahoM Let me answer one bit at a time, otherwise it will be a mess. `From my understanding, aren't we SUPPOSED to find $δ$ and that means we can't assume it?`. You don't need to find $\delta$, proving its existence is enough. To prove it exists, it's also enough to find it. This is the usual course of action. Regarding the assumption thing, one technique people like to use is this: OK, I don't know what $\delta$ is, but let's assume I have it and see what conditions I need to impose on it for this to work".

Comment: Do you get the idea? Once these conditions are found, you're supposed to take a specific $\delta$ and confirm it actually works. Often people disregard this part because the reasoning that led to restriction on $\delta$ is for most, convincing enough. I myself prefer to forget the previous work, pick a $\delta$ that works and prove what I have to prove.

Comment: So you assume a random $\delta$ like 1 and see what needs to be done to make it work ? Also why is my proof wrong ?

Comment: @DemahoM I may have misunderstood you. What you assume is that $|x-a|<\delta$, without knowing what $\delta$ is. Then you try to make something out of this as I described in my comment. I see your other question has already been answered by another user.

Comment: If you assume $|x-a|<\delta$ which I understand since it is a hypothesis then WHY you also assume $|x-a|<1$ ? Sorry if these questions are repetitive but I do understand the structure of the logic sentence that's why I cant understand how assuming $\delta=1$ although the ONLY thing we can assume is $|x-a|<\delta$.

Comment: @DemahoM I should say that I don't completely understand your question (or Spikav's argument, there seems to be somehting missing), which is why I was vague regarding the last part. BUT either $|x-a|<1$ or it isn't. If it is, something happens (see Spivak). If it isn't, then $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2|a|+1}$ is enough. So $\delta =\min\left(1,\frac{\epsilon}{2|a|+1}\right)$ works.

Comment: @DemahoM I [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/696665/55235) answer of mine might be helpful to you. It concerns sequences, but the ideas are the same.

Comment: @DemahoM I got the Spivak book. I read the relevant part. What he does is what I explained. Either $1$ is good enough or not, if it isn't, then well, $\frac{\epsilon}{2|a|+1}$ is good enough. So it suffices to take $\delta =\min\left(1,\frac{\epsilon}{2|a|+1}\right)$.

Comment: Yeah I kept reading your answer until I suddenly understood it. The idea of making a hypothesis that must satisfy TWO conditions was a little bit unclear for me at first. As for the $sin$ part the problem was that I assumed the converse without making sure the proof is correct as you said:"Once these conditions are found, you're supposed to take a specific δ  and CONFIRM it actually works".

Answer (score 2):

In response to:

> Finally,
>
> $|x|<\epsilon|1+sin^2x|<2\epsilon$ $\implies$ $|x|<2\epsilon=\delta$
>
> But when I plug $\epsilon=0.2$ then the $\delta=0.4$. If I put my
>   $x=0.3<0.4$ then the answer is $0.3>0.2=\epsilon$.
>
> What am I doing wrong here ?

What you're doing wrong is trying to reverse the direction of the implication from $\Longrightarrow$ to $\Longleftarrow$.

It's certainly true that if $|x|$ is less than $\epsilon|1+\sin^2x|$, then $|x|$ is also less than $2$ times $\epsilon$.  For that matter, $|x|$ is less than a *gazillion* times $\epsilon$.  But the converse need not be true.

What you should really do is ask not how *big* $\epsilon|1+\sin^2x|$ can be, but how *small* it can ever be.  The answer to that is clearly $\epsilon$, since $\sin^2x\ge0$ for all $x$.  Using *that* for $\delta$ -- i.e., letting $\delta=\epsilon$ -- we have

$$|x|\lt\delta\implies|x|\lt\epsilon\implies|x|\lt\epsilon|1+\sin^2x|\implies\left|{x\over1+\sin^2x}\right|\lt\epsilon$$

Comment: Can you please then tell me how $|x-a|<\frac{\epsilon}{2|a|+1}$ is logically correct since  $|x−a|<\epsilon |x+a|  >ϵ 2|a|+1 $.

Comment: Sorry for the above equation: Here is the correction $|x-a|<\frac{\epsilon}{|x+a|}>\frac{\epsilon}{2|a|+1}$.