# Proving $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sin(n)/n = 0$ using epsilon definition

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

So the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ of $\frac{2\sin(n)}{n}$ is $0$.

How do I prove this?

I say;

$$|\frac{2\sin(n)}{n} - 0 | = |\frac{2\sin(n)}{n}| < \epsilon$$
for which $n$'s ?

Not sure how to get rid of the absolute value bars, or even what to do next. First day with series and convergence in class!

Comment: See my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696574/another-epsilon-n-limit-proof-question/696665#696665) for an explanation of the process.

Answer (score 3):

Use the fact that $\lvert \sin(x) \rvert \leq 1$ for all $x$. Then, you should be able to get a nice $N$ for a fixed $\varepsilon$.