# prove the limit using definition. $\lim_{(n) \rightarrow (\infty)} \frac{7n^2+9n-17}{4n^2-5n+6}= 7/4$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, epsilon-delta

- $\lim_{(n) \rightarrow (\infty)} \frac{7n^2+9n-17}{4n^2-5n+6}= 7/4$

I got that $|\frac{71n-110}{16n^2-20n+24}| < $  $\epsilon$ , how do I continue from here ?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696574/another-epsilon-n-limit-proof-question) answer might help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is, for any $n\ge 3,$ $$\left|\frac{7n^2+9n-17}{4n^2-5n+6}- \frac74\right|= \left|\frac{71n-110}{16n^2-20n+24}\right|<\frac{71n}{16n^2-20n}=\frac{71}{4(4n-5)}<\frac{71}{4(n-2)}.$$

Can you finish now?