# Evaluate a limit using only the definition of limits

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

I have the following expression which I need to prove using **only** the $|a_n - L| < \epsilon$ thing
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n + 1 \over n} = 1$$
Normally I could do it but my problem is that I cant lose the root so Im stuck at this expression:
$$\frac{1 - \epsilon}{ \epsilon} < n\sqrt{n+1 \over n}$$
So I cant get to something like n < ...
Im sure there is a better way to approach it,

Any help appreciated thanks

P.S
I thought about saying that I can do square on the first equation but can I really do it? and even if so I think Im not allowed to do it in this question

Comment: Seems like you have an extra $n$ in the inequality. That inequality doesn't seem to be related to the limit at all. Given $\epsilon>0$, what do you think you need to find?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696574/another-epsilon-n-limit-proof-question/696665#696665) answer can help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\left|\;\sqrt\frac{n+1}n-1\;\right|=\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n}{\sqrt n}=\frac1{\sqrt n\left(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n\right)}$$

Take now **any** $\;\epsilon>0\;$ . We want to check for which $\;n$' s we have

$$\frac1{\sqrt n\left(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n\right)}<\epsilon$$

But now we can *estimate* :

$$\frac1{\sqrt n\left(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n\right)}\le\frac1{\sqrt n\sqrt n}=\frac1n$$

So it is enough to know when

$$\frac1n<\epsilon\iff n>\frac1\epsilon$$

and we're done.

Comment: Why couldn't you say that $1 \over \sqrt n \sqrt n$ $ =$ $1 \over n$ $ \le n$ which means that $n < \epsilon$

Comment: @kfir Because I want to bound the expression in my first line above. I also could say that for all $\;n\in\Bbb N\;,\;\;\frac1n<56778\implies 56778<\epsilon\;\;??!$ Of course not, as I don't get to **choose** $\;\epsilon\;$ .

Answer (score 6):

Assuming $n, \epsilon > 0$,
$$\begin{align*}
\left|\sqrt{\frac{n+1}n}-1\right| &< \epsilon\\
\left|\sqrt{1+\frac1n}-1\right| &< \epsilon\\
\sqrt{1+\frac1n}-1 &< \epsilon\\
\sqrt{1+\frac1n} &< 1 + \epsilon\\
1+\frac1n &< (1+\epsilon)^2\\
\frac1n &< (1+\epsilon)^2-1\\
n &> \frac1{(1+\epsilon)^2-1}\\
n &> \frac1{2\epsilon + \epsilon^2}\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: This is exactly the sort of solution the answer I linked in the question yields.

Comment: @GitGud based on this + the solution you posted can I also say that $\sqrt{n+1 \over n}$ $< $ $(n + 1) \over n$ and then do my equation based on it?

Comment: @kfir124 Yes, in the notation of my answer you'd have $h(n)=\dfrac{n+1}n-1$ which coincidentally yields the same thing as Timbuc's answer.

Comment: @GitGud You know I've just thought about it and couldn't I say that $n + 1 \over n$ $- 1$ $ =$ $1 \over n$ $< n$ which means I could just say that $n < \epsilon$ ? (which is not the same as Timbuc's answer)

Comment: @kfir124 You should be focusing on $h(n)<\varepsilon$ with is equivalent to $\frac 1 n<\varepsilon$, just like Timbuc's answer.

Comment: @GitGud but couldn't I take it even further and simplify it to the max? I mean why not keeping with this method till I get just $n$

Comment: Because the target inequality is something that looks like $g(\varepsilon)<n$. The inequality $\frac 1 n<n$ doesn't help with this.

Comment: @GitGud $\sqrt{n + 1 \over n} - 1 $$\le$$ n+1 \over n$ - $1$$ $$\le $$1 \over n$$\le n < \epsilon$ can I say that?

Comment: @kfir124 Since you are evaluating limit for $x\to\infty$, you need to find, for any $\epsilon>0$, a lower bound $N(\epsilon)$ such that for all larger $n > N(\epsilon)$, $\left|\sqrt{\frac{n+1}n}-1\right|<\epsilon$. Finding results like $n<\cdots$ is not going to prove the limit to infinity.

Comment: @peterwhy So why could I say that $\sqrt{ n + 1 \over n}$ $< $ $n + 1 \over n$ and then prove it for $n + 1 \over n$

Comment: @kfir124 Because if you manage to deal with something that is larger, then necessarily something that is smaller will be dealt with automatically. Peterwhy, sorry for flooding your inbox.

Comment: @GitGud I wish they gave the option to PM other users(or did they and Im not aware of it?) and yes but $n$ is larger than all of these $blabla \over n$ stuff so Im ending up with $n < \epsilon$ immediately (look at my comment at Timbuc's answer)

Comment: @kfir124 Say I set $\epsilon = 3.14159...$ (which is quite large, just illustration here). Solely from your $n<\epsilon$ conclusion, for what $n$ is $\left|\sqrt{\frac{n+1}n}-1\right|<\epsilon$? Next, I tighten $\epsilon$ to $0.1$, for what $n$ does $\left|\sqrt{\frac{n+1}n}-1\right|<\epsilon$?

Comment: @peterwhy Yea I see that it is not logical but I dont understand the rules of "estimate": saying that $\sqrt {n+1 \over n}$ $\le$ $n + 1 \over n$ is valid, and saying that $\sqrt {n+1 \over n}$ $\le$ $1 \over n$ is valid(I think?) but saying that $\sqrt {n+1 \over n}$ $\le$ $n$ is 100% not valid which I dont get why mathematically is not valid I do get it logically

Comment: You cannot overdo it beyond the point where you can still say $n\color{red}>\cdots \implies \left|\sqrt{\frac{n+1}n}-1\right|<\epsilon$.

Comment: @kfir124 You can PM other users just as you've been doing, but since this is peterwhy's answer, he will always get pinged.

Comment: @GitGud Oh I meant a real private message in such way that only the receiver can see it. And peterwhy your last comment saved my head from exploding I really needed this math rule or else I would have gone crazy :) I wish i could give you rep for your comment =]

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. Prove that $\forall \varepsilon > 0\exists N \forall n>N: \sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n}} > 1 - \varepsilon$ and $\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n}} < 1 + \varepsilon$.