# What's the general technique to show a sequence converges?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

After "guessing" what the limit of a particular sequence is, what's the general process to prove that this sequence indeed converges to it? (using the definition)

(The definition says that a sequence ${x_n}$ converges if for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists  $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for $n>N$, the distance between $x_n$ and the "guessed" limit point is less than $\varepsilon$.)

Comment: I believe my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696574/another-epsilon-n-limit-proof-question/696665#696665) is exactly what you want.