# Proving by definition: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {1-n^2}{2n^2+n+5}=-\frac 1 2$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, epsilon-delta

> Prove by definition that: $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {1-n^2}{2n^2+n+5}=-\frac 1 2$

Scratch work to find $N\in \mathbb R$: $|\frac {1-n^2}{2n^2+n+5}+\frac 1 2|=\frac {n+7}{4n^2+2n+10}\color{red}{<}\frac {n+7}{n^2}=\frac 1 n+\frac 7 {n^2}<\epsilon$ so take $N=max\{\frac 1 {\sqrt\epsilon},\frac 7 \epsilon\}$.

But this $N$ leads me to this expression: $\epsilon +7\sqrt\epsilon$ which I don't think is correct. I'm not sure the red $<$ is correct but I don't see any other way to make the denominator smaller...

Note the polynomial in the denominator has no solutions, so it can't be simplified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The red inequality might or might not always true, I don't know, didn't check (**edit:** it's obviously true because $n$ is always positive). But it will be true for big enough $n$ and that's good enough. Proceed with $\dfrac 1 n+\dfrac 7 {n^2}\leq \dfrac 1 n+\dfrac 7 n=\dfrac 8 n$.

Comment: Hmm with $\frac 8 n$ or $N=\frac 8 \epsilon$ I still get to an expression that has a sum of epsilons... 

In the example you gave, $\frac {n+7}{2n}=\frac 1 2 +\frac 7 {2n}$ which doesn't go to $0$ so that way is wrong no?

Comment: Pick $N=\frac 8\varepsilon$ and suppose $n>N$. It follows that $\frac 8n<\frac 8N=\varepsilon$. Can you finish?

Comment: I see. Shouldn't we reach an expression smaller than $\epsilon$ if we place $N=\frac 8 \epsilon$ in $\frac {n+7}{4n^2+2n+10}$ ?

Comment: @kuhaku I don't understand the question. Can you rephrase it, please?

Comment: In other words, take: $\frac {N+7}{4N^2+2N+10}=$ (replacing $N$ with $\frac 8 \epsilon$) and after a few inequalities getting the result that this is smaller than $\epsilon$.

Comment: We want to prove that for all $n> \frac 8\varepsilon$, it holds that $\left|\dfrac {1-n^2}{2n^2+n+5}+\dfrac 1 2\right|<\varepsilon$, yes? Can you prove this?

Comment: I think I got it, it's basically the same work I did in my question only a different parameter... Thanks again Git Gud.

Comment: @kuhaku You're welcome. [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696574/another-epsilon-n-limit-proof-question/696665#696665) might interest you.