# Prove by definition of a limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

I have this example here:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{2}+1}{n^{2}+n+1} = 1$

so I have to prove that, $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists n_{0}\in N, \forall n(n \in N) \geq n_{0} \Rightarrow |\frac{n^{2}+1}{n^{2}+n+1} - 1| < \epsilon$

I have done in these steps  
  
$|\frac{n^{2}+1}{n^{2}+n+1} - 1| < \epsilon$  
  
$|\frac{-n}{n^{2}+n+1}| < \epsilon$  
  
$\frac{n}{n^{2}+n+1} < \epsilon$  
  
$n^{2} + n(1-\frac{1}{\epsilon}) + 1 > 0$  
  
D = $(1-\frac{1}{\epsilon})^{2} - 4 = (1 - \frac{1}{\epsilon} - 2)(1 - \frac{1}{\epsilon} + 2) = -(1 + \frac{1}{\epsilon})(1-\frac{1}{\epsilon}) = \frac{1}{\epsilon^{2}} - 1$

### $n_{1,2} = \frac{\frac{1}{\epsilon} - 1 \pm \sqrt{D}}{2}$

I guess we need that

### $n > \frac{\frac{1}{\epsilon} - 1 + \sqrt{D}}{2} = \frac{\frac{1}{\epsilon} - 1 + \sqrt{\frac{1}{\epsilon^{2}}- 1}}{2} = \frac{\frac{1}{\epsilon} - 1 + \sqrt{1 + (\frac{1}{\epsilon^{2}}- 2)}}{2} > \frac{\frac{1}{\epsilon} - 1 + \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{\epsilon^{2}}- 2)}{2}  = \frac{\frac{1}{\epsilon} - 1 + \frac{1}{2\epsilon^{2}}- 1}{2} = \frac{\frac{1}{2\epsilon^{2}} +\frac{1}{\epsilon} -2}{2}$

But I think I have done some mistakes and this last thing could be in more simple form

P.S: How can I verify whether my result $n(\epsilon)$ is true in the end?

Comment: I didn't read everything, but note that $\forall n\in \mathbb N\left(\frac{n}{n^{2}+n+1}<\frac 1{n}\right)$ so you can instead deal with the simpler inequality $\left|\frac 1 n\right|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: hmm, am I allowed to do so? and you did figured out that it's less than 1/n^2 from just looking at it?

Comment: I had a typo in my comment, I didn't meat for the denominator to be $n^2$, but rather $n$ (I fixed this). [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696574/another-epsilon-n-limit-proof-question/696665#696665) might interest you.

Comment: your given link explains lots of things, that were missed in my textbook, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes you don't want to be too precise with your estimates.  A loose estimate with a nice form that gets the job done is often easiest.

Here's a start:

$|\frac{n^2+1}{n^2+n+1}-1|=\frac{n}{n^2+n+1}<\frac{n}{n^2}=\frac1n$

Comment: *"Sometimes you don't want to be too precise with your estimates. A loose estimate with a nice form that gets the job done is often easiest."* +1 for this one. :)

Comment: so my walkthrough can be calld wrong in this case? and how do I check my result?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure whether or not your walkthrough is correct; I'm trying to point out a less messy direction.  I do note that sometimes the discriminant ($D$) of your quadratic may be negative, which could produce even more difficulties in your solution.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left|\frac{n}{n^2+n+1}\right| <\epsilon\\\left|\frac{n}{n^2+n+1}\right| <\left|\frac{n}{n^2+n}\right| <\left|\frac{n}{n(n+1)}\right| <\left|\frac{1}{n+1}\right| <\epsilon\\n+1 >\frac{1}{\epsilon}\\n>\frac{1}{\epsilon}-1\\n\geqslant \left \lfloor \frac{1}{\epsilon}-1 \right \rfloor $$

Answer (score 0):

$|\frac{-n}{n^{2}+n+1}| < \epsilon \Leftrightarrow |\frac{n}{n^{2}+n+1}| < \epsilon   $  
  
Now $|\frac{n}{n^{2}+n+1}| < |\frac{1}{n}| $ . So if $n_0=\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ everything is ok.