# Simple convergence proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

I'm asked to prove, using the definition of convergence, that limits approach a certain value.

For example, $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{n^2+4}{n^2}.$$ I can see that it converges to $1$, but I'm not sure how to go about the proof of it using the definition of convergence. (There exists an $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, $\mid x_n-x\mid<\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$ )

Comment: See a similar, more complicated example [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696574/another-epsilon-n-limit-proof-question).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that

$$\left|\frac{n^2 + 4}{n^2} - 1\right| = \left|\frac{4}{n^2}\right| = \frac{4}{n^2}\tag{*}$$

Given $\epsilon > 0$, the rightmost side of $(*)$ is less than $\epsilon$ when $n$ is greater than $\ldots$