# Using the definition of the limit sequence, find $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n}{n^2-2}$ for $n=2,3,4,...$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Using the definition of the limit sequence, find $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n}{n^2-2}$ for $n=2,3,4,...$

I've tried to isolate n but its impossible to do.

Comment: Write $n^2-2=(n+\sqrt{2})(n-\sqrt{2})$, note that $n/(n+\sqrt{2})\to 1$ and that $1/(n-\sqrt{2})\to 0$.

Comment: I know the limit is 0 but im trying to solve this using epsilon,n and N

Comment: You say "for $n=2,3,4,…$", but that is what $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ is for. Not sure if you added this for better understanding or if there is a well-hidden misconception somewhere. If in doubt: do ask.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696574/another-epsilon-n-limit-proof-question/696665#696665) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac n {n^2-2}=\frac 1 {n-\frac 2 n}$$.

Thus for $n$ large enough, $$0<\frac 1 {n-\frac 2 n}<\frac 2{n}$$ and if you decide not to make use of the fact that $2\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1 n=0$, you can use *epsilontic* on the later and transfer the method to the prior.

Answer (score 0):

Use partial fractions, using the factorization that **ForgotALot** gave in his comment.

$\frac{n}{n^2-2}=\frac{a}{n+\sqrt{2}}+\frac{b}{n-\sqrt{2}}$, for some $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$. The limit on this as $n\rightarrow\infty$ is 0, since the denominators get arbitrarily large while the numerators stay the same.