# Proving ${\lim\limits_ {n\to\infty}}\frac{6n^3+5n-1}{2n^3+2n+8} = 3$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, infinitesimals

I'm trying to show that $\exists \,\varepsilon >0\mid\forall n>N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that:
$$\left|\frac{6n^3+5n-1}{2n^3+2n+8}-3\right| < \varepsilon$$
Let's take $\varepsilon = 1/2$:

$$\left|\frac{6n^3+5n-1}{2n^3+2n+8}-3\right| = \left|\frac{6n^3+5n-1 - 6n^3 -6n -24}{2n^3+2n+8}\right| < \left|\frac{-n -25}{2n^3+2n+8}\right| = \left|-\left(\frac{n +25}{2n^3+2n+8}\right)\right|$$

Since $|-x| = |x|$:

$$\left|-\left(\frac{n +25}{2n^3+2n+8}\right)\right| = \left|\frac{n +25}{2n^3+2n+8}\right|<\varepsilon $$

This is the part which I have trouble with. Here, I always end up with my minimum-required index to be smaller than zero, which seems peculiar to me:

$$\left|\frac{n +25}{2n^3+2n+8}\right| < |n+25| = n+ 25 < \varepsilon  = 1/2$$
From here, I will get that my $N$ will be less than zero,  which means that all the elements of the sequence are inside of my given epsilon environment, but I know that's not true since $a_1 = 5/6 < 3 - \varepsilon $, so what I did do wrong? Is it because I completely removed the denominator? If so, why does that break the inequality?

Comment: Yes $\left|\frac{n+25}{2n^3+2n+8}\right|\lt|n+25|$ but this will not allow you to solve the limit in question. I suggest writing instead $\left|\frac{n+25}{2n^3+2n+8}\right|\lt|\frac{1}{n^2}|$ for large enough $n$.

Comment: You don't want to show that there exists $\varepsilon$, you want to show that any positive $\varepsilon$ satisfies the property.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696574/another-epsilon-n-limit-proof-question/696665#696665) for a similar example, and also for general strategy.

Comment: It seems that you want $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ (or $\varepsilon$-$n_0$) proof - which suggest that the ([tag:epsilon-delta]) tag might be suitable here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't worry about $\epsilon$.
Instead,
try to get the difference
in a simple form
by assuming $n$
is as large as you need.
Then getting $n$
is much simpler.

Using your calculations:

$\begin{array}\\
\left|\dfrac{6n^3+5n-1}{2n^3+2n+8}-3\right| 
&= \left|\dfrac{6n^3+5n-1 - 6n^3 -6n -24}{2n^3+2n+8}\right|\\
&= \left|\dfrac{-n -25}{2n^3+2n+8}\right|\\
&= \left|\dfrac{n +25}{2n^3+2n+8}\right|\\
&\le \left|\dfrac{2n}{2n^3}\right|
\qquad\text{if } n \ge 25\\
&= \left|\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right|\\
&\lt \epsilon
\qquad\text{if } n \gt \frac1{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore the difference
is within $\epsilon$
if
$n \gt \max(25, \frac1{\sqrt{\epsilon}})$.

You don't have to get
the best possible $n$ - 
just showing one exists
is good enough.

Comment: Well, I worry a little bit about $\varepsilon$, when the first sentence of the OP starts with "$\exists \,\varepsilon >0\mid\forall n>N\in\mathbb{N}$".

Comment: $N = 1/\sqrt{\epsilon}$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that for $n\geq 1$ we have $n+25\leq n+25n=26n$ and $2n^3+2n+8\geq 2n^3$ so you have that $$\left|\frac{n+25}{2n^3+2n+8}\right|\leq \frac{26n}{2n^3}=\frac{13}{n^2}$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 2):

I do it like this:

$\forall n \ge 1, \; \dfrac{6n^3 + 5n - 1}{2n^3 + 2n + 8} = \dfrac{6 + 5n^{-2} - n^{-3}}{2 + 2n^{-2} + 8n^{-3}}; \tag 1$

since it is easy to see that

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} (6 + 5n^{-2} - n^{-3}) = 6, \tag 2$

and

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} (2 + 2n^{-2} + 8n^{-3} ) = 2, \tag 3$

we have

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{6n^3 + 5n - 1}{2n^3 + 2n + 8} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{6 + 5n^{-2} - n^{-3}}{2 + 2n^{-2} + 8n^{-3}} = \dfrac{\lim_{n \to \infty}( 6 + 5n^{-2} - n^{-3})}{\lim_{n \to \infty} ( 2 + 2n^{-2} + 8n^{-3})  } =   \dfrac{6}{2} = 3.  \tag 4$

Of course, such an answer, though perfectly rigorous and on point,  is bound to be less than satisfactory to readers who want, as the text of the question indicates, to see the $\epsilon$-$N$ mechanism operate in detail; what I have done here is simply invoke standard and elementary results on the behavior of limits; we may also cast things into $\epsilon$-$N$ form if we write

$\dfrac{6 + 5n^{-2} - n^{-3}}{2 + 2n^{-2} + 8n^{-3}} - 3$
$= \dfrac{ 6 + 5n^{-2} - n^{-3} - 3( 2 + 2n^{-2} + 8n^{-3})}{2 + 2n^{-2} + 8n^{-3}}$
$=\dfrac{5n^{-2} - n^{-3} - 6n^{-2} - 24n^{-3}}{2 + 2n^{-2} + 8n^{-3}} =  \dfrac{-n^{-2} - 25n^{-3}}{2 + 2n^{-2} + 8n^{-3}} ; \tag 5$

$\left \vert \dfrac{6 + 5n^{-2} - n^{-3}}{2 + 2n^{-2} + 8n^{-3}} - 3 \right \vert =  \left \vert \dfrac{-n^{-2} - 25n^{-3}}{2 + 2n^{-2} + 8n^{-3}} \right \vert; \tag 6$

it is evident *via* inspection of the right-hand side of this equation that, given any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a sufficiently large $N \in \Bbb N$ that

$n > N \Longrightarrow \left \vert \dfrac{-n^{-2} - 25n^{-3}}{2 + 2n^{-2} + 8n^{-3}} \right \vert < \epsilon, \tag 7$

which in light of (6) by definition implies

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{6 + 5n^{-2} - n^{-3}}{2 + 2n^{-2} + 8n^{-3}} = 3, \tag 8$

completing an $\epsilon$-$N$ demonstration of the requisite limit.

It appears to me that our OP Fatima Ens' principal error lies in
confusing the roles of $\exists$ and $\forall$ in the definition of limit; the quantifying symbol string should read

$\forall \epsilon \exists N \mid \forall n > N \; \text{and so forth}; \tag 9$

if this correction is accepted and the remaining statements bought into accord with this (corrected) version, the chances of completing a successful proof are greatly enhanced.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why everyone is making this so long and drawn out.

You only need remember this: as $n\to \infty$; $t\geq0\implies n^{t+1}-n^t\to\infty$

In other words, given $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{P(n)}{Q(n)})$ where $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials, only the largest powers (as long as they are positive) and their coefficients count.

So:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg[\frac{6n^3+5n-1}{2n^3+2n=8}\bigg]=\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg[\frac{6n^3}{2n^3}\bigg]=\lim_{n\to\infty}[3]=3$$