# Any tips for $\varepsilon(-\delta)$-proofs?

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

This is more of a general question.

We recently started to work with $\varepsilon(-\delta)$-proofs but then quickly went on to find propositions that make it easier to show a series, function etc. converges. The thing about these proposition is that they often can only be applied when certain criteria is met, whereas $\varepsilon(-\delta)$-proofs can be seen as the all-purpose method. And I think it would be pretty powerful to always be able to prove something with the $\varepsilon(-\delta)$ approach, in an exam for example.

But then again - it's (at least for me) pretty hard to find the fitting $\varepsilon$ or $\delta$ for some problems.

To those of you who are more experienced: Is there a method or heuristic that make it easier to find own $\varepsilon(-\delta)$-proofs or is it really just "seeing by pondering"?

Comment: Of course there is no answer to this question.
$\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proofs can be easy to find, or really hard. 

I think most people avoid them. The method is more fitting theoretically then to use on a concrete example.

Also these proofs are most of the time done in two parts.
The first part is a scetch of the proof, to find the choice of $\delta$. 

After that you conclude the proof.

Comment: So you kinda never have to 'see' the (or one) choice for $\delta$, but deduce it by some calculation, which involves most of the time stipulation which is the crucil part in every $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof.

Comment: The typical method is to "work backwards."

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696574/another-epsilon-n-limit-proof-question/696665#696665) doesn't answer your question, but it answers a closely related one (basically the same question, but for sequences). The same principles apply, but it's not trivial to make the translation.

Comment: "by hook or by crook", my professor used to always say.

Comment: One thing I like to do when I get stuck is set $\delta=\min\{-,1\}$ where I have to determine what $-$ is. This kind of just forces $\delta\leq 1$ and so I can go and try to find some more inequalities to work with from the problem.

However, there is no one trick that solves all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

You have to find a function $\delta$ such that for a given $\epsilon$

$$|x-x_0|<\delta(\epsilon)\implies|f(x)-L|<\epsilon.$$

Assuming that $f$ is strictly increasing (hence invertible), the right inequality can be read as
$$f^{-1}(L-\epsilon)<x<f^{-1}(L+\epsilon)$$

and a suitable $\delta$ is given by

$$\delta(\epsilon)=\min(|f^{-1}(L-\epsilon)-x_0|,|f^{-1}(L+\epsilon)-x_0|).$$

This also works when $f$ is decreasing.

If $f$ has extrema, making it non-invertible, you can constrain $\delta$ to be smaller than the distance to the nearest extremum.

In practice, you will simplify/approximate the expression of the inverse, making sure to get a tighter interval.

Comment: Many thanks for the downvote.

Comment: I like this heuristic, thanks.